# System of inequalities with square roots

Tags: inequality

I have the following two inequalities for variables p and q:

$p<\sqrt{p^2-4q}$

$p<-\sqrt{p^2-4q}$

how can I find the solution? I used a piece of software to graph both inequalities as written and then I could see where the two graphs intersect, hence I could see the solution. However, I´d like to solve this problem in a more "mathy". How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a system, add inequalities together to obtain that $p<0$. Then subtract inequalities to get $\sqrt{p^2-4q}>0$ which is always true as long as $p^2-4q \ge 0 \implies p^2 \ge 4q$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $p<0$ and $q \geq 0$.

If $q<0$ then the second inequality cannot hold for any $p$. If $q \geq 0$ then the second inequality holds for all $p$ and the first one holds iff $p <0$.